# Change Gnome display resolution from commandline

Tags: command-line, screen, display-resolution

I hae a Ubuntu 18.04 box with gnome 3.28.2. I have a CRT screen attached that has gone bad and does not want to display the set resolution of 1600x1200 anymore. It will do lower resolutions (checked with another machine).
I'm trying to change the gnome display resolution using from a ssh login but I can't get this to work.
xrandr does not work in ssh.
I tried adding xrandr --output default --mode 1024x768 --rate 60 to /etc/gdm3/Init/Default and restart gdm3 but that does not work, the whole script does not seem to be run. Also /etc/gdm3/Init/Display does not work.

I can get into the terminal screen from Gnome with Ctrl-Alt-F2 and do things there (without seeing what I type) but also there xrandr does not work. I tried fbset as well but that also does not work.
Surely gnome must have the display resolution somewhere in a configuration file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome Display Manager (GDM) stores monitor resolution in the files
`~/.config/monitors.xml` in a per-user basis. This affects the resolution for one user after login into the GDM.
To set it globally (also on the login screen), copy a ready-configured monitors.xml to `/var/lib/gdm/.config/monitors.xml`.

Source:
[https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM#:~:text=Setup%20default%20monitor%20settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM#:%7E:text=Setup%20default%20monitor%20settings)